# How to create SEO friendly react application created from create react app?

Tags: reactjs, seo, create-react-app, react-helmet

```
<meta property="og:url" content="mysite.com/" />
<meta property="og:type" content= "article"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="content title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="content description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/image.jpg" />
```

React helmet is unable to update the meta tag of index.html file. I have deployed my application in nginx server which renders index.html file for all routes. There is no any server side routing done for this project. How to fix this issue ?